# nmap skip port scan but execute --script?

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to use nmap with a script which works with a normal scan. But when executing `nmap -sn --script=...` it just finds the host (target) and stops.

What would the command be to scan the target with the script but not do a port scan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSE ([Nmap Scripting Engine](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html)) scripts are designed to run based on the return value of at least one of four functions (called [Rules](http://nmap.org/book/nse-script-format.html#nse-format-rules))defined in the script:

- `prerule()` - This function is run once at the beginning of the entire scan. If it returns true, then the `action` function is called with no arguments.
- `portrule(host, port)` - This function is run once for every open port on every host. If it returns true, then the `action(host, port)` function is run for that host and port combination.
- `hostrule(host)` - This function is run once for every host that is found to be up. If it returns true, then the `action(host)` function is run for that host.
- `postrule()` - This function works the same as the `prerule` but is run *after* all hosts have been scanned.

So when you scan with `-sn` ("skip port scan"), the `portrule` scripts will not run at all, since there are "no open ports." The best way to do a targeted script scan is to determine what the relevant ports are and specify them with `-p`. For instance, if I wanted to run [`ssh-hostkey`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html) without doing a full port scan, I would do this: `nmap -p 22 --script ssh-hostkey <targets>`

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: Yeah I thought it should be provided a option to run only script without port-scanning.